# Xterm: No absolute path found for shell: 500

Tags: ubuntu, xterm

After sshing (using putty with X11 enabled) into my virtual box VM, I tried to open an xterm window. However the following command:

```
xterm -sb 500
```

or even

```
/usr/bin/xterm -sb 500
```

returns the error:

```
xterm: No absolute path found for shell: 500
```

I cant seem to figure out what the error even means!

EDIT:

```
ls -la /usr/bin/xterm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 450888 Sep 28  2012 /usr/bin/xterm

alias xterm
-bash: alias: xterm: not found


DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.10"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="12.10, Quantal Quetzal"
```

Comment: Not installed? What is the version of Linux and the output of `ls -la /usr/bin/xterm`?

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you meant

```
xterm -sl 500
```

The [`-sb` option](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#OPTIONS:-sb) uses no value.

The [manual](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html) page for these options:

```
   -sb     This  option  indicates  that  some  number  of  lines that are
           scrolled off the top of the window should be saved and  that  a
           scrollbar  should  be  displayed  so  that  those  lines can be
           viewed.  This option may be turned on  and  off  from  the  "VT
           Options" menu.
```

and the [`-sl` option](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#OPTIONS:-sl):

```
   -sl number
           This option specifies the number of lines  to  save  that  have
           been  scrolled  off the top of the screen.  This corresponds to
           the saveLines resource.  The default is "64".
```

Comment: On putty: `PuTTY X11 proxy: unable to connect to forwarded X server: Network error: Connection refused
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0` On VM Console: `XT error: Cant open Display! XT error: DISPLAY not set`

Comment: That's a different question, related to your X-forwarding.

Comment: setup x11 forwarding in putty and the server you are trying to reach `cat /etc/ssh/ssh_config`

Comment: yeah options are set.. but it still does not work. Ill open up a new question.